# What was the purpose of the ‘overlay number’ field in the MZ executable format?

Tags: ms-dos, file-format, executables

Many materials covering the layout of MZ executables ([RBIL, for example](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/214b.html#table-01594), and even [a comment in MS-DOS 2.0 source code](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v2.0/source/EXEC.ASM#L108)) describe the word at offset +0x1a as the ‘overlay number’, with the value zero representing the main executable.

I don’t recall ever seeing an MZ-format file that keeps any other value there, and as far as I can tell, the DOS executable loader does not use this field in any way.  What was it used for?

Comment: The checksum is also virtually unused. I think the overlay number field was intended for use by the linker and/or the produced application. As you observed DOS never uses it.

Comment: At least we know how the checksum field was supposed to be used… for the most part.

Comment: It was common at that time to split an executable into overlays which would get loaded when need (e.g. Turbo Pascal did that). So my guess is that this filed marked an executable as an overlay, and the INT 21 "EXEC" you linked has a subfunction "load overlay" that I assume would have been used for it (but I never have seen anyone using it).

Comment: But why number them?

Comment: @user3840170 so that the running executable can tell which overlay is in memory

Comment: The Amiga executable file format also had provision for overlays which I don't ever recall seeing used.

Comment: Also note that overlays were commonly used on CP/M as well. WordStar, NewWord, spreadsheets and other programs supported it. Turbo Pascal supported overlays as well - both for CP/M and MS-DOS.

Answer (score 24):

### TL;DR: The Number is Used to Manage Multiple Overlays in a single EXE File.

Microsofts linker (LINK) can create single EXE files containing multiple overlays (up to 63) which are simply numbered in sequence. The first in sequence is always 0 and the one loaded as program if executed directly by DOS. Each Overlay within the file is essentially an EXE file (structure) with it's own MZ header.

Runtime **support is not provided by DOS' [EXEC](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v2.0/source/EXEC.ASM)**, but an (often) language specific *Overlay Manager* which may or may not use DOS' [Load Overlay](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/51/29.html) function. Link replaces all calls to a function in an overlay other than the one executed by an INT call (default [3Fh](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/48/61.html)) followed by overlay number and entry point.

The whole process is described in great detail (from a linker's perspective) in the _The MS DOS Encyclopedia; Article 20: The Microsoft Object Linker; [Overlays p.715ff](https://archive.org/details/The_MS-DOS_Encyclopedia_Ray_Duncan/page/714/mode/2up?q=%22Overlay%20Manager%22).

---

### The Details

Ever wondered why huge programs like WORD can run on memory tight PCs and still hold considerable data in access? Overlays it is. Instead of the whole program only it's main and maybe most common used routines are loaded into memory. Everything else is only loaded on demand. Kind of a user space swapping. By arranging code according to usage (and maybe duplicating some) these loads could be kept in check that even working from diskettes was acceptable.

Using overlays was *the* way of executing larger programs than main memory (or the memory assigned) in the time before virtual memory (*1). DOS as a real memory OS, intended for small machines was from the start made to support this. Except, to keep DOS itself small, the code to fully manage overlays was not included. DOS only supports to load the first overlay from an EXE file. Depending on the function used for loading this would be either handled as a regular program, or as overlay.

Programs could use this to have overlays loaded into their 'overlay area' by using DOS function 4Bh/03h [Load Overlay](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/51/29.html) - to make it work every overlay had to be kept in a separate file.

Then again, the EXE format was on purpose created in a way to support multiple chunks of 'content', like additional information, precreated data or more general any form of resource. Such resource would be simply added added to the EXE file after the program. Usually at a 512 byte boundary, using the word at offset 4h of the [EXE-header](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/it/94/15.html) as linkage pointer. Microsoft used this in two cases, adding debug information and supporting multiple overlays in a single file. Both managed by [LINK](https://archive.org/details/The_MS-DOS_Encyclopedia_Ray_Duncan/page/700/mode/2up), Microsoft's linker.

A program (A) with two overlays (B,C)(*2) can be linked by marking them as such with parenthesis:

`LINK A+(B)+(C)`

will produce an EXE file with three overlays with according overlay numbers:

0. Program A (Main)
1. Overlay B
2. Overlay C

When executing this, only the Program A will be loaded into memory. All references in either of the three to any overlay other than the own will not be marked up in the relocation table, but replaced by the linker into a sequence of

```
        INT    3Fh
        DB     <overlay number (1,2)
        DW     <offset function address>
```

The interrupt to be used can be changed with the linker option /O:int#. Usually the program (A) will be linked also with an overlay manager which intercepts that interrupt and use the following values to perform the needed transition:

- The INT is invoked,
- the active Overlay is noted on stack
- the overlay manager looks up the requested overlay number,

  - if not loaded:

    - the new Overlay is loaded (*3)
    - it's number is recorded as active
- a CALL to the offset within the overlay is performed

When returning the process runs in reverse:

- Execution returns to the overlay manager
- previous Overlay number is poped from stack
- if not loaded:

  - that Overlay is loaded (*4)
- its number is recorded as active
- return address on stack is incremented by 3
- an IRET is executed.

It's easy to see that specialized overlay managers could as well have more than one overlay in memory a any time. Given only if installed memory permits this :))

---

### The Other Way

Borland did as well offer some overlay managers. In fact there seem to have been at least 3 different versions.

- One private version build into [Turbo Pascal 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal#Version_2) that worked the same way under CP/M and DOS (all within a single 64 Ki segment)
- A third party "Overlay Manager for Turbo Pascal" by [Turbopower Software](http://www.turbopower.com/) for Turbo Pascal 3.0 which seemed to have used INT 3Fh as well.
- And VROOM (Virtual Realtime Object Oriented Memory *4), delivered with Turbo Pascal 6. It was way more sophisticated and supported use of XMS/EMS memory for extrem fast witching of small sized overlays. Described in great detail in [this article](https://secondboyet.com/articles/publishedarticles/theslithytove.html).

---

*1 - In fact, it's, as [Puppydrumm64 reminds](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/22718/puppydrum64), a strategy well known by console programmers as well. After all, Games had as well a tendency to grow larger than the available ROM address space, so rather sophisticated schemes of bank switching were developed ... essentially hardware supported overlay managers :))

*2 - Sure each of A/B/C can consist of multiple object files, left that out for simplicity.

*3 - Yes, that's exactly the point where that overlay number in the EXE header is used: the overlay manager walks the file (*5) until it finds the requested number noted at offset 1Ah.

*4 Thanks to [Jerry Coffin](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25739/what-was-the-purpose-of-the-overlay-number-field-in-the-mz-executable-format/25742#comment87478_25742) for remembering the name ... I only recalled it being something like ZOOM :)

*5 - Ok, any overlay manager worth its money will only walk it once and note the offsets in a table for faster access, wouldn't it?

Comment: AmigaOS also has overlayed executables.for the same reason, and overlay code chunks must be managed manually from the overlay manager. Must have been fun to write such managers...

Comment: Overlays were an old idea, common on mainframes.

Comment: So it's kind of like bank switching on NES and Game Boy cartridges? So if I understand this right, let's say my main program has a `call foo` which references a function `foo` in Overlay C. So the LINK program would replace my `call foo` with `INT 3Fh DB 2 DW foo`?

Comment: @puppydrum64 yes, that's a valid comparison. Banked game ROMs are very much a kind of hardware supported overlays. Of course they may bring their own kind pitfalls :))

Comment: There were third party linkers as well as MS Link - e.g. Blink (which I think did even more and automatically) and Plink-86 which was the main one I used and allowed overlays on overlays.

Comment: All the references to Borland's overlay manager that I can recall used the name "VROOM" ("Virtual Realtime Object Oriented Memory"). Of course, there was nothing object oriented about it, beyond that fact that it came out when OO was the hot new thing (and possibly, some OO programming used enough more memory to need overlays worse).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you for looking that up. The name was just some faint memory as I never used Buch of borland beside eraly Turbo Pascal on CP/M (to write programs for customers using IBM PC/XT machine).

Comment: @Raffzahn: I'll blame it on age, but I didn't have to look it up. Easier to remember stupid marketing crap from 35 years ago than to remember what I had for breakfast this morning.

Comment: @puppydrum64 note that bank switching is *completely free* while overlay switching involves loading several kilobytes from disk. Yes, I was also confused the first time I decompiled a Game Boy cartridge and saw it "switching overlays" every few instructions.

Comment: @user253751 Overlay design is a software structure that can be implemented my many different technologies. Loading from disk is one possible way of implementation, banking another. Not just with ROM, buit as well using RAM. Think doing Overlays with EMS.

Comment: @user253751 So it's more like a `rep movsw` then.